# What is the use of Generic Parameters like T, U, V, S, E?

Tags: java, generics

What is the use of Generic Parameters like T, U, V, S, E?

What is the use of generic params in Java?

I have an understanding on Type T parameter and wildcard of its uses. Still I have been lagging with other Parameters.

The most commonly used type parameter names are:

E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S, U, V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

I found these in [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

I need an explanation for the type parameters S, U, V etc.

Comment: `S`, `U` and `V` are just the letters nearest to `T` if you need more than one type.

Comment: They are just names. The letter doesn't matter.

Comment: Apart from their possible meaning, generics can be named whatever you want. You can also declare a generic class like `class MyClass<MY_GENERIC_TYPE>`.

Comment: Thank you @BackSlash for the useful info. Still i need some explanation.

Comment: @PushkalPrakash The answer is the one by Lutz Horn. Types `S` and `U` are likely used because they are letters nearest to `T`. Letters with a specific meaning (`K` for `Key`, `V` for `Value`, etc) are documented in that link you provided, so I assume everything else was just used because near to that letters. Also, if you look at JDK source code you won't find specific usecases that explain the use of those letters, so this suggests they don't have a specific meaning.

Comment: You need a tutorial on Java generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter used doesn't matter. It is just a good practise to pick something kind of sensible (K/V for Key and Value, E for element, etc.) just like it is a good practise to have descriptive variable names.

The reason the Jave supports generic types is that if you couldn't have a List then you need to have ListOfString, ListOfBoolean, ListOfMap, ListOfListOfString, etc. In other words, having generic types allow you to reutilize one implementation of a Class rather than having to create a new implementation specific to each type that the class should work with.
There's quite a bit more to understand about generic types in Java but that is the first basic thing to understand about them.

Comment: Did that clarify things or are you still unclear on why/when generic parameters are used in Java?

Comment: Till now I'm fine with the detail explanation. If i have any issues i will share with you. And i need best practices used with generics.

Comment: @Pushkal Prakash if the answer satisfy you, you should accept it.

Comment: @ThomasMartin I don't have any issue accepting the fact. I'm satisfied.

Comment: Yes so you should accept the answer, which means putting a green tick on it, so other people know your problem is solved.

Comment: @ThomasMartin please guide me if there are any tutorials links with detailed explanation. I need some clarification still i'm not fulfilled.

Comment: Tutorial about accepting answers ? Read the tour :  https://stackoverflow.com/tour